# Delayed function (colorchange) with jquery in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, settimeout, delay

Hello there people of the internet.

I'm new to stackoverflow and javascript/jquery, trying to learn it at the moment.

My Problem right now is:

I want to have a box which is black by default and changes its color to blue every second. It should then stay blue for about 0,2 seconds and get back to its default color (black). This whole action should repeat itself over and over again in a loop. I read something about *setInterval* and *delay*, but I'm not really sure, if that could help my problem in any way.

My code so far is this:

```js
var box = $("#box");

function changecolor(){
box.css("background-color", "blue")
}
setTimeout(changecolor, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#box{
  
background: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Is CSS an option? Or, is this some sort of JS challenge?

Comment: Sort of JS challenge.

Answer (score 0):

In the function you can test for the color and then call the timeout which recursively calls the same function:

```js
var box = $("#box");

function changecolor() {
  if (box.css("background-color") === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    box.css("background-color", "blue")
    setTimeout(changecolor, 200)
  } else {
    box.css("background-color", "black")
    setTimeout(changecolor, 1000);
  }
}
changecolor()
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#box {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Comment: My apologies Mark, I didn't mean to edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge in this is that you need to swap colors at a different delay.

Using `setInterval w/setTimeout` will mean that you're transition between blue->black is cut short by ~200ms (rather than the full 1000ms), as setInterval will be a fixed time between colors. Basically, you're swapping colors within the 1000ms.

One solution to this is to call `setTimeout` continuously, and pass a different delay value.

Here's an example:

```js
var box = $("#box");

function colorChanger (delay) {
    // If delay is 1sec, set color to black.
    // Otherwise, we set color to blue.
    var color = delay === 1000 ? "black" : "blue";

    // Apply color to element
    box.css("background-color", color);

    // The color set above will be changed when this
    // timer is called (either 1 sec for black
    // or .2 sec for blue. Within the timer, we will
    // flip the delay (if 1sec, next iteration will be 
    // 0.2 secs)
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Flip for next loop
        colorChanger(delay === 1000 ? 200 : 1000);
    }, delay);
}
// Kick off color changer
colorChanger(200);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#box {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the setInterval method and do something like this:

```
var box = $("#box");

var count = 0;
function changecolor() {
if (count == 0) {
  box.css("background-color", "blue");
  count = 1;
}
  else {
    box.css("background-color", "black")
    count = 0;
  }

}
setInterval(changecolor, 200);
```

`setInterval()` runs the function `changecolor()` every 200 ms. We use a variable to keep track of what colour to update to. If it's 0 we update it to blue otherwise black.